# reverse of itertools.groupby?

Tags: python, functional-programming

I'm composing generators together for some data processing. I first batch the data generator for threading in an API call like:

```py
from itertools import groupby, count
def batch(data: List[Any], size=4):
    c = count()
    for _, g in groupby(data, lambda _: next(c)//size):
        yield g
```

which i then feed to the threader to do an API call

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
def thread(data: Iterable, func: Callable, n=4):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=n) as executor:
        for batch in data:
            yield executor.map(func, batch)
```

now I'm trying to merge the batches back into a list/generator for use down stream in the generator pipeline. I tried this

```py
from itertools import chain
def flat_map(batches: Iterable):
    for i in list(chain(batches)):
        yield i
```

But `i` seems to still be a generator and not an item from the list?

Comment: If this were ready for copy&paste&testing, I could test what I think would fix it...

Comment: `chain(*batches)`?

Comment: The standard library uses [`chain.from_iterable(starmap(...))`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.3/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L642) in one location where this pattern is needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wanted `chain(*batches)` or `chain.from_iterable(batches)`. `chain(batches)` is basically just yielding the same values as using `batches` directly would get you, it just adds a layer of wrapping. So the correct code (without `list`ifying, which is almost certainly wrong here) is just:

```
from itertools import chain
def flat_map(batches: Iterable):
    return chain.from_iterable(batches)  # chain(*batches) would also work, but if batches is an iterator itself, it would be forced to eagerly run to completion first; chain.from_iterable can begin work when the first batch is ready
```

you don't even need `yield` since the iterator is already producing what you want. If you need it to be a true generator, just replace `return` with `yield from` for a similar result.

Also note: You might avoid the need for the function entirely by just changing:

```
yield executor.map(func, batch)
```

to:

```
yield from executor.map(func, batch)
```

so `thread` is flattening as it goes in the first place.

Comment: How about `flat_map = chain.from_iterable`?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode: Sure, why not? If the `typing` annotations match, it'll be equivalent. Some people like named wrappers, but it works either way.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up with the three functions condensed into one:

```py
from itertools import chain, groupby
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def spread(data: Iterable, func: Callable, n=4):
    """ Combines `batch`, `thread` and `flat_map`"""
    c = count()
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=n) as executor:
        for _, batch in groupby(data, lambda _: next(c)//n):
            yield from executor.map(func, batch)
```

So I just needed `yield from` to get this to work.
Thank @ShadowRanger!